# Why is it that CTS frame doesn't have a Transmission address

Tags: wireless-networking

I was wondering why is that the frame of a CTS or a ACK for 802.11 doesn't have a transmission address?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's to save airtime by keeping the frames short by leaving out redundant information.

The Transmitter Address (TA) of the Ack is known because Acks must be sent within a short window of time after the frame being Acked, and nothing else is allowed to transmit during that Ack window. So the Receiver Address (RA) of the frame being Acked must be the TA of the Ack.

In the original design of 802.11, the TA of the CTS was known because only the AP could issue a CTS, and also because the CTS followed an RTS, so the RTS RA must be the CTS TA, and must always be the AP. Later amendments to 802.11 allowed non-AP STAs to issue CTSes to themselves, which means the unstated TA of a CTS is now ambiguous. It could be the same as the RA, or it could be the BSSID.